# running multiple command from bash script with out loosing control

Tags: bash, git-bash

I want to run these two command in a loop:

```
for i in cat input:
do
    winpty Kubectl exec -it $i -n image -c podname -- sh
    2nd command
done
```

When I am running the .sh file, the first command works fine and after than nothing is happening.Can anybody help on this?I am running through `gitbash` from windows machine

Comment: Is that `2nd command` supposed to be run *by* `winpty Kubectl exec ...` (i.e. passed as input to that command), or is it supposed to run as a separate command after `winpty Kubectl exec ...` finishes? If it's supposed to be passed as input, you need to put it in something like a here-document. Also, are you really trying to loop over the strings "cat" and "input"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bash rookie, but maybe it's because of the lack of a defined `-d` directory for unzipped files?

Comment: do I need to add directory? Basically the first command is doing some ssh and then opening the new terminal but then I am loosing the control, 2nd command is not even running..